# Integrating Google API into Unity 3D

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-maps-api-3, augmented-reality

First of all I'd like to introduce myself.
I am a third year student Undertaking a Networking Bachelor,
for my final project we have been given the task of developing an Augmented Reality app ( Yeah I know, programming project for a networking student ..)

Anyway my group and I have little to no programming experience and we were helping to yield some help from you guys.
We have been able to achieve a fully working compass, Hard coded in some objects and have the app accessing the camera.

Our app consists of tokens being spawned throughout random locations , (we have been told our app has to be similar to Pokemon GO) the user then collects these tokens and rewards them with a health food discount at a store like boost, sumo salad etc.

However we have reached a point in our task where we are struggling to find any good information on how this can be done.
Please excuse our ignorance as we are still new to learning the code,
We are using UNITY 3D and coding in C #

Comment: https://developers.google.com/unity/

Comment: And for what you need GoogleAPI? For a project like that, I strongly recoment [Vuforia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iU5gC6fZbf4) because it does everythig you want to do. Or if you doesn't want to use any third API you can check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNwduUQrlJs). Your "tokens", what are these? Like a coordinate in Maps?

Comment: Never mind! I just read your tags, If you need to get the maps coordinates and a texture to display in Unity, you can use some [plugins](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/search/page=1/sortby=relevance/query=google&maps)